# Dropbox iOS Chooser in the Simulator

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I am working on using the iOS Dropbox Chooser. I was able to integrate as expected via their [documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/ios)

However, in the simulator, the chooser will ask you to have the dropbox app installed to authenticate. Is there any way that I can deal with this so that I can actually get a file from my dropbox while in the simulator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can, no. In recent OS versions Apple has done a great job of making more functionality available in the simulator (you used to be able to use hardly any external functionality at all, but many things work there now). However the Dropbox app is completely separate from Apple. It doesn't come pre-installed on the Simulator, and short of having the Dropbox App's source code and building *that* to your simulator first, there's no way to do this.

It's unfortunate, but really it's best to test things on-device anyway, so you're probably better off going that route. Good luck! :)

Comment: This is (no longer?) true. Download the latest DropBox iOS SDK from the Dropbox website and build and run the included example app, DBRoulette, in the simulator. It downloads a random photo from your dropbox account and displays it.

Comment: Colin: Dropbox Chooser is a specific extension that requires the Dropbox app to be installed, as it uses the dropbox app itself for file selection. It's different than the Core and Sync APIs.